# Get key and value of object array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, ajax

Guys I am taking the values in array of object and hitting the webmethod from ajax but I am not able to get the key and values of that array. Below is my ajax code

```
var ShedulerTableCount = $('#dvSave table').length;
            var ShedulersData = [];
            ShedularCount = new Object({ ShedulerCount: $('#txtTimeSeries').val() })
            ShedulersData.push(ShedularCount);
            for(var k=1; k <= ShedulerTableCount ; k++)
            {
                var tableId = $('#tblTimeInterval' + k);
                tableId.find('tbody tr').each(function (i, el) {
                    Shedularobj = new Object({ ShedularName:'',InterVal: '', TimeSeries: '', LockingPeriod: '', TradeDuration: '', Min: '', Max: '', Touch: '', NoTouch: '', IPG: '', IPGDeduction: '', Closeable: '', txtTimeSeries: '', txtGap: '', txtRollingInterval:'' });
                    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
                    Shedularobj.ShedularName = 'sheduler ' + k;
                    Shedularobj.InterVal = $tds.find('label').eq(0).text();
                    Shedularobj.TimeSeries = $tds.find('label').eq(1).text();
                    Shedularobj.LockingPeriod = $tds.find('input').eq(0).val();
                    Shedularobj.TradeDuration = $tds.find('input').eq(1).val();
                    Shedularobj.Min = $tds.find('input').eq(2).val();
                    Shedularobj.Max = $tds.find('input').eq(3).val();
                    Shedularobj.Touch = $tds.find('input').eq(4).val();
                    Shedularobj.NoTouch = $tds.find('input').eq(5).val();
                    Shedularobj.IPG = $tds.find('input').eq(6).val();
                    Shedularobj.IPGDeduction = $tds.find('input').eq(7).val();
                    Shedularobj.Closeable = $tds.find('input').eq(8).val();
                    Shedularobj.txtTimeSeries = $('#txtTimeSeries').val();
                    Shedularobj.txtGap = $('#txtGap').val();
                    Shedularobj.txtRollingInterval = $('#txtRollingInterval').val();
                    ShedulersData.push(Shedularobj);

                });
            }

      $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "BinarySetting.aspx/SaveShedulers",
                    data: "{ShedulersData:" + JSON.stringify(ShedulersData) + "}",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Success');
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

And this is my c# code from where I want to fetch the key and value of the object:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string SaveShedulers(object[] ShedulersData)
    {
        object objCount = ShedulersData[0];
       // System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = objCount.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        var ss =  objCount.GetType().GetProperties().Single(pi => pi.Name == "ShedularCount").GetValue(objCount, null);
        return "ss";
    }
```

I am also going to attach the screenshot to understand the scenario more clearly:

[image]

Comment: How about `ShedulersData[0].Key` and `ShedulersData[0].Value`

Comment: how you fill data in ShedulersData in client side?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava there is not any key property in this otherwise I can easily get this  have only methods in it that is GetType()

Comment: @SURJEETSINGHBisht I have update my question to show how I am filling the data in ShedulersData

Comment: Cast your object to a class type that has Key and Value properties and that should solve it.

Comment: @Oluwafemi any example you have?

Comment: @vishuminhas no it is not correct. if you want key value in ShedulersData
 then you have two properties in ShedulersData object which is key and value.

Comment: @SURJEETSINGHBisht can you elaborate how I can correct this so I will fix it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class in your code behind like this

```
public class SchedulerTuple
{
   public string ShedularName { get; set; }
   public string InterVal { get; set; }
   public string TimeSeries { get; set; }
   public string LockingPeriod { get; set; }
   public string TradeDuration { get; set; }
   public string Min { get; set; }
   public string Max { get; set; }
   public string Touch { get; set; }
   public string NoTouch { get; set; }
   public string IPG { get; set; }
   public string IPGDeduction { get; set; }
   public string Closeable { get; set; }
   public string txtTimeSeries { get; set; }
   public string txtGap { get; set; }
   public string txtRollingInterval { get; set; }
}
```

and then change the paramaters of your webmethod to a List like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveShedulers(List<SchedulerTuple> ShedulersData)
{
    // your code here
}
```

if you want to pass other values to your code behind like the scheduler count, then add another argument instead of packing a lot of stuff in a single object.

I don't think you need to use reflection here. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Danish ideas, modify the ajax call like this.

```
   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "BinarySetting.aspx/SaveShedulers",
                        data: ShedulersData, //<-------------
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Success');
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
```